# Activity animation transition

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

[image: desire]

I  want transaction animate my activity A to Activity B **where Activity B comes from big zoom from left side(ZOOM OUT+SLIDE FROM LEFT) and fits in the screen** and  **Activity A diminishes moves to right and then vanishes** .

For more clarity install this[LINK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.narendramodiapp&hl=en) app and see the transitions when the bottom navigation bar is clicked.

Made below Demo Video the activity animation which i want

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwQT0R-dFfs)

Comment: what second is the animation in the video?

Comment: @azizbekian animation when moving from one activity to another

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can set your app-wide transition scheme via `styles.xml` file in the values folder of your app resources.

For this, create a style `"WindowAnimationTransition` and include it in your `AppTheme`

Here is a short example:

```
    <style name="WindowAnimationTransition">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
</style>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimationTransition</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

As you can see, there are `@android:anim` pre-defined animations available but you can place your own here as well.
For a list of available out-of-the-box animations see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.html 
There you find Fade, Explode, Slide and all the predefined stuff.

Comment: i ahev added video of the animation which i want https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwQT0R-dFfs&feature=youtu.be